# Sonarqube shows Coverage percentage but no unit tests

Tags: sonarqube, coverage.py

I'm having a problem with the Sonarqube report. It is showing 42.5% for test coverage, but "-" Unit Tests.
I created the report with coverage.py and with the command
`coverage run --branch --omit 'venv/*,tests/*' -m unittest`.

I've set up my coverage path with the following line:
`sonar.python.coverage.reportPaths=coverage.xml`
I couldn't find a solution online and don't know if it's a problem while generating the report or importing it to Sonarqube. Here is a picture of the report:

[image]

Thanks in advance!